# Importing datetime raises ModuleNotFound 'math' in Python script when executed by command line

Tags: python, python-3.6

I'm using Ubuntu 17.10. While developing a simple script I added the line

```
from datetime import datetime
```

and tried to run the script by command line with:

```
python complete.py
```

but then it shows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "complete.py", line 4, in <module>
    from datetime import datetime
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/datetime.py", line 8, in <module>
    import math as _math
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'math'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 12, in <module>
    import subprocess, tempfile, os.path, re, pwd, grp, os, time
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 136, in <module>
    import _posixsubprocess
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_posixsubprocess'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "complete.py", line 4, in <module>
    from datetime import datetime
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/datetime.py", line 8, in <module>
    import math as _math
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'math'
```

If I run the script in PyCharm IDE, I have no errors. I already checked my python version by running

```
python -V
```

it shows:

```
Python 3.6.3 :: Anaconda, Inc.
```

What am I missing?

Comment: If your replace `from datetime  import datetime` with `import math`, does it still throw the error?

Comment: Seems that this is an Anaconda-specific issue.
Try re-installing it a few times and it may fix itself.
https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/172

Comment: @MegaIng It shows the same message. `No module named 'math'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've updated my OS to Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic Beaver), the following steps will still works if you're using other version, but it's still worth to mention that I'm no longer in 17.10 version as the stated in the original question.

Turns out that even with `python -V` showing something with Anaconda, the python command was still pointing to some python2.7. I found that after installing django and trying to run  `python3 -m django --version` to check if the version was right and it showed a message saying that django wasn't installed.

What I did was: `conda install -f python`, to make sure I had an updated python version. Anaconda files are stored in `/home/<user>/anaconda/` dir. I checked the `/bin` dir and there were some python files and some links to python3.6;

Checked the `/usr/bin` dir with and `ll` command and thus found: `python -> python 2.6`(!). So my problem was that, even running python -V, and it showing 3.6.3, it was actually running a 2.6. Not sure how. What I did next:

`sudo mv /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python.bk`

and finally

`sudo ln -s /home/<user>/anaconda/bin/python /usr/bin/python`

Comment: Works well, especially when you do not want to create a sub-environment for conda and want your base environment to run python 3